# given int X,find Y such that (X+Y) is pallindrome in binary format.works fine with values upto 12345 not working with values 123456 and above

Tags: java

```
public class aevi{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        long num=s.nextLong();
         long i=0,j;
         while(i<num)
         {
             long p=1,sum=0,reversesum=0;
             j=num+i;
             while(j>0)
             {
                 System.out.print(j%2+" ");
               sum+=(j%2)*p;
               p=p*10;
               j=j/2;
             }
             long r=sum;
             System.out.print(r+" ");
             while(sum!=0)
             { 
               reversesum=(reversesum*10)+(sum%10);
               sum=sum/10;
             }
             System.out.println(reversesum);
             if(reversesum==r)
               {System.out.println(i);
             break;}
           i++;
         }

     }
}
```

whats wrong with this code.The program is about " given a number X.find minimium positive integer Y required to make binary representation of
(X+Y) palindrome.for eg:X=6 Y=1".It works fine with values upto 12345 but it is not working with values 123456 and above.

Comment: What’s not working? Wrong result? Exception thrown? Computer blows up? Did you try debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

To tell the truth, it is hard to read your code and find problem. I think it is too complicated with such simple problem. I offer you another solution.

E.g. you entered `x=6`, this is `110` in binary format. Your goal is to find another minimal value `y` that `x+y=<binary palindrome>`. For `110`, maximum palindrome id `111` which is `7`. So, all you need is just find a minimal `0 <= y <= (7-6)` where `x+y=<binary palindrome>`.

Here is the code example. It is pretty easy and simple.

```
public static long toBinaryPalindrome(long num) {
    for (long i = 0, total = allBits(Long.toBinaryString(num).length()) - num; i <= total; i++)
        if (isBinaryPalindrome(num + i))
            return i;

    return -1;
}

private static boolean isBinaryPalindrome(long num) {
    String str = Long.toBinaryString(num);
    return str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
}

private static long allBits(int len) {
    long res = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        res |= 1 << i;

    return res;
}
```